# USB 3.0 hard drive not recognised

Tags: 18.04, windows, usb-drive

Drive not recognised, it seems, by either USB 3.0 port or USB 2.0 port.

Windows recognised it. I transferred files.

After connecting the drive to the USB 3.0 of a machine running  Ubuntu 18.04, (and after a wait for the connection attempt to peter out) dmesg reported this:

```
$ dmesg

[169126.008899] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[169126.032037] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0621
[169126.032042] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[169126.032044] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 20181108
[169126.033931] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected

[169126.034973] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-2:1.0

[169126.195773] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[169126.195799] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[169126.205975] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[169126.206001] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 

[169127.807519] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HGST HTS 542020A7E660          PQ: 0 ANSI: 6

[169127.809017] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0

[169127.809215] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[169127.809598] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[169127.809600] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 3b 00 00 00
[169127.810000] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[169127.810004] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[169127.832818]  sdc: sdc1
[169127.834338] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[169129.780917] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd

[169165.980471] usb 4-2: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[169171.100537] usb 4-2: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[169176.476447] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169181.852508] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169182.060401] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[169187.484415] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169192.860458] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169193.068363] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[169198.492424] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169203.868520] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169204.076287] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[169209.500291] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169214.876218] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169215.084150] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[169215.140359] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[169215.148240] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[169215.148252] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request
[169215.148302] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[169215.148305] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 00 00 00 08 00
[169215.148307] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
[169215.148345] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 488378624, async page read
[169220.508875] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169225.884116] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169226.092125] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[169231.516160] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169236.892208] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169237.100094] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 13, error -62

[169237.128148] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle
[169243.292064] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169248.668070] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169248.876792] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 14, error -62

[169254.300038] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169259.675930] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169259.883946] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 15, error -62

[169259.912022] usb usb4-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[169265.307942] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169270.683973] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169270.891833] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 16, error -62

[169276.315777] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169281.691832] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169281.899806] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 17, error -62

[169281.927873] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle
[169288.091813] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event

[169288.091859] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[169290.107782] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command

[169290.315618] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 18, error -62
[169300.635720] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Command completion event does not match command

[169300.635731] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[169302.651717] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for stop endpoint command

[169307.803656] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[169307.803661] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[169307.803663] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[169312.923668] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event

[169314.939527] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[169314.939540] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 32.

[169314.939545] usb usb4-port2: couldn't allocate usb_device

[169315.105188] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[169315.105217] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[169315.115402] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[169315.115430] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24
```

lsusb said this:

```
$ sudo lsusb -v -s 4-2:1.0

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            4.15
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           31
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
```

Then tried it in a Windows machine and found it worked.

Plugged it back into the Ubuntu machine's USB port, and dmesg reported this:

```
$ dmesg
[175390.069501] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[175395.189459] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[175397.205418] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[175397.205431] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 32.
[175397.205437] usb usb4-port2: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

Tried it then in a USB 2.0 port, and dmesg reported this:

```
[175598.684168] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175598.795773] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0621
[175598.795776] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[175598.795777] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20181108
[175598.796467] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[175598.802424] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[175598.957489] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[175598.957517] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[175598.967793] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[175598.967821] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[175600.824666] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HGST HTS 542020A7E660          PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[175600.825716] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[175600.827132] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[175600.828436] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[175600.828439] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 3b 00 00 00
[175600.829798] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[175600.829802] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[175600.858324]  sdc: sdc1
[175632.591899] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175632.707535] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[175663.311697] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175666.135670] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175666.347715] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175666.559678] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175666.775683] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175666.987670] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175667.199679] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175667.310596] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[175667.310604] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 00 00 00 08 00
[175667.310607] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
[175667.399694] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175667.611671] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175667.827665] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175668.039670] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175668.255683] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175668.467668] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175668.578592] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[175668.578599] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 00 00 00 08 00
[175668.578602] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
[175668.578610] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 488378624, async page read
[175669.083610] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175700.175472] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175705.283487] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175720.899403] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175721.087342] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175726.275298] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175741.891194] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175742.079260] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175752.771151] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 6, error -110
[175752.851138] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[175763.523167] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 6, error -110
[175763.524083] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[175763.530723] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[175763.530741] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request
[175763.530770] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[175763.530776] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 74 3f 00 00 08 00
[175763.530781] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907023935
[175763.530950] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[175763.530952] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511936, async page read
[175763.530955] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[175763.530956] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511937, async page read
[175763.530958] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[175763.530959] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511938, async page read
[175763.530960] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[175763.530961] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511939, async page read
[175763.631028] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[175763.779172] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[175763.779202] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[175763.789495] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[175763.789526] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[175768.771063] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175784.387043] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175784.574954] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[175789.763006] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175805.378892] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175805.487147] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[175806.090848] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[175816.770803] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 9, error -110
[175816.850723] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[175827.522668] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -110
[175827.523044] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Then disconnected a chained USB hub that is also connected to another USB 2.0 port, and connected the problematic USB drive to a USB 2.0 port again, and dmesg reported this:

```
[175784.387043] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175784.574954] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[175789.763006] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175805.378892] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[175805.487147] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[175806.090848] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[175816.770803] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 9, error -110
[175816.850723] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[175827.522668] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -110
[175827.523044] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[176024.401123] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[176024.401129] usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[176024.401133] usb 3-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[176024.401137] usb 3-1.2.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[176024.401465] usblp0: removed
[176024.464074] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176024.464091] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176024.474320] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176024.474348] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176029.553129] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[176032.625011] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176032.737882] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0621
[176032.737890] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[176032.737894] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20181108
[176032.738790] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[176032.739109] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[176032.889595] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176032.889617] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176032.899801] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176032.899820] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176034.554529] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HGST HTS 542020A7E660          PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[176034.554957] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[176034.556206] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[176034.557769] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[176034.557772] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 3b 00 00 00
[176034.559146] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[176034.559158] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[176034.591793]  sdc: sdc1
[176034.672983] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR mismatched command completion event
[176036.689031] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for configure endpoint command
[176036.689474] usb 3-1.2.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 12
[176041.840894] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[176041.840903] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[176041.840940] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
[176041.877332] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Slot 11 endpoint 2 not removed from BW list!
[176041.879584] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Slot 9 endpoint 2 not removed from BW list!
[176041.879914] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Slot 8 endpoint 2 not removed from BW list!
[176041.880213] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Slot 7 endpoint 2 not removed from BW list!
[176041.961551] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176041.961570] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176066.764791] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176066.883035] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[176097.484530] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176100.296554] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176100.508537] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176100.720534] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176100.932559] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176101.144473] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176101.356445] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176101.467981] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[176101.467990] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 00 00 00 08 00
[176101.467993] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
[176101.556448] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176101.768507] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176101.980496] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176102.192547] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176102.404431] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176102.616428] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176102.727582] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[176102.727589] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 00 00 00 08 00
[176102.727593] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
[176102.727601] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 488378624, async page read
[176103.200388] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176134.348281] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176139.456170] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176155.072148] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176155.260066] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176160.448083] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176176.063939] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176176.251976] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176186.943756] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -110
[176187.023871] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[176197.695773] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -110
[176197.696670] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[176197.702878] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[176197.702886] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request
[176197.702900] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[176197.702904] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 74 3f 00 00 08 00
[176197.702906] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907023935
[176197.702924] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[176197.702927] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511936, async page read
[176197.702931] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[176197.702933] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511937, async page read
[176197.702935] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[176197.702936] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511938, async page read
[176197.702938] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1
[176197.702939] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1953511939, async page read
[176197.801673] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[176197.930618] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176197.930644] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176197.940822] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=926135 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[176197.940850] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:1d13:0f7a:8abf:4f14 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=292671 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[176202.943757] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176218.559514] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176218.747563] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[176223.935474] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176239.555463] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[176239.663662] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[176240.267390] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[176250.943354] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 14, error -110
[176251.023359] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[176261.695196] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 15, error -110
[176261.695553] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The chained USB hub then did not work when I reconnected it. But a USB mouse worked fine when then removed from the hub and connected instead direct to a USB 2.0 port on the machine.

Perhaps it's a dicky drive? But why then would it seem to work fine in Windows?

UPDATE:

Windows can't actually format the drive. So it does seem like dicky hardware.

Comment: If it is dicky hardware, please delete the question.

Comment: Based on the output of `dmesg` shown in the question, I think it is possible to infer that this is a hardware problem. In particular, I believe the timeout messages and the "device not accepting address 11, error -62" messages strongly suggest hardware failure. Although questions that turn out to be due to hardware problems are often considered off-topic as "a problem that can't be reproduced," I think that in this case it should [be answered](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) with information about how it appears to be a hardware problem as the drive stopped working on Windows too.

Comment: Eliah: yours seems like an answer. I will tick it so if you make a proper answer of it.

Comment: user68186: I will not delete the question, because if it is a hardware problem, it would be useful for other people trying to find out why their USB drive isn't working... indeed the drive did work on Windows, it merely wouldn't format on Windows.